# Github releases - How to deploy releases

Tags: git, github

I was reading about the **Github releases** and seems like it would be a good fit for your project. As we need to decided which feature to take it to the production and which not to.

The part I am not able to understand is, how does master and release branches plays role in this.

> Should I create a releases from release branch or develop branch?

.

> I am not able to see a way to create a pull request from `releases` (not release branch) to master? so not sure from where I should deploy to Production Environment.

**Note**: releases and release branch are two different thing. releases is very sepecific to github. 
I am talking about this https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-releases

Comment: We create the release branch from develop. Any final bug fixes go into that. We take that branch to production and merge it to master and develop only when we know the release is fine and not rolled back.

Comment: @Sreeram I am not talking about branch, I am talking about releases which is very specific to Github

Comment: Sending it to production and merging is equal to creating a Github release I thought.

Comment: Releases on Github are based on commit hashes or tags. When you click to create a new release, you can choose the branch to use for the release -- this is up to how you organize your repository, and isn't required to be on the `master` branch or `release` branches at all.

Answer (score 0):

A GitHub release is a way to associate deliverables (executables generally, but also any other files, like for instance like a hash file to check the integrity of the executable) to a tag or branch.

The goal is to associate deliverables to a specific source code commit, with the assumption that said deliverable was *built* from said source code, and that you could reproduce or debug later that executable from the source.

But the process makes no assumption as to which branch you chose: it is entirely up to you.

Comment: yes, I understand that, I can create releases from any branch. However, I have develop and release branch corresponds to Dev and QA environment.  How does this release fit in accordance to production branch?

Comment: @GaurangShah It fits in that you can create a release from a tag you set on the production branch.